# trying to see expected output using stack

Tags: java

I have written a code that parses the given input. I have been trying to fix it about three hours. But I can't get expected output. However, I'm new in stack usage and Java. Can someone help me? `Issue is fixed.`

Expected output:

```
START -> INPUT
-> EXP
-> EXPI
(+ EXPI EXPI)
(+EXPI Id)
(+Id Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `while (!stackCopy.Pop().Equals("("))` you had 2 tokens before `"("`, so `idCon.Push("EXPI");` was called twice. As a result the condition `if (temp.Equals("EXPI"))` was met twice and `"EXPI"` was printed in the last line.

Comment: so ? I can't figure out the solution, Could you show me ? @guy

Comment: You call `stackCopy.pop();` twice, why not third time?

Comment: I don't think you don't understand my problem. I call twice because according to input I have two EXPI. So, I need to replace two EXPI with Id step by step in output. I think you don't run my code as well.

Comment: @guy is correct here. I suspect the `break;` is not doing what you think it's doing. It jumps you out of the inner `while` loop after the first iteration, so it has only changed one `EXPI` to an `Id`. The first time it hits the `break;`, your `idCon` stack looks like: `(, EXPI, Id`, then it immediately jumps to the `System.out.println(")";` line and decrements `i`.

Comment: I understand your problem. In the fourth line in `Call` you have `stackCopy.pop(); stackCopy.pop();`. That's leave **two** `"EXPI"` in `stackCopy` when you push it to `idCon` (I know because I did run your code) which means `if(temp.equals("EXPI"))` is true twice and you print `"EXPI"` after the `"Id"` print in `"else { System.out.print(temp); } "`.          Good luck.

Comment: so, how can it be fixed ? @guy

Comment: second going in the `while` loop I hope to get `(, Id, Id` instead of `(, EXPI, Id `@DaveyDaveDave